# Degrees of freedom in translational motion

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

**According to this Wikipedia article** [Degrees of freedom (mechanics):](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(mechanics))

> 1. The position of a single railcar (engine) moving along a track has one degree of freedom because the position of the car is defined by the distance along the track.
> 2. A single particle in space requires three coordinates so it has three degrees of freedom.

**According to my Mechanics textbook:**

> - A rigid body moving in a translational motion has 3 degrees of freedom.

---

**1. What's the difference between the rigid body in my textbook and the railcar in the Wikipedia article?**

**2. How many DOFs does a point particle moving in a translational motion have?**

- Shouldn't it be treated just like a rigid body in translational motion (since the body doesn't have rotations)?
- If so, how can a constrained point particle have 3 DOFs (the same DOFs as a particle that is not constrained in motion)?

Comment: If your rigid body can move in any direction in space, then there's three independent directions and so 3 translational DOF. (This does assume that the rigid body does not rotate, which seems a strange assumption.) That said, the phrase "linear motion" seems confusing: I'd prefer translational motion, to avoid the implication that said body is moving in a straight line.

Comment: Yes, "along a track" limits the railcar to one DOF, but if no such constraint is given in your textbook one would assume you can move in 3 dimensions, and hence 3 DOF. Does your textbook give any more context or clarification of the constraints on the motion of the rigid body? To answer the parenthetical question in @Semiclassical's comment above, the term "translational" is what rules out the possibility of rotational motion which would indeed add more DOF.

Comment: @David No, the only constraint given is that it is moving in a translational motion.  
Is there a difference between moving "along a track" and "in a translational motion"?

Comment: @Semiclassical I changed "linear" to "translational". TBH, I can't tell which English term is a more accurate translation of the one used in my textbook. And like David said I assumed the body doesn't rotate because it's in "translational" motion. I guess it's a fair assumption.

Comment: In the real world, a track confines a railcar to moving in only 1D whereas a car, can move in any direction on the surface of the Earth so has 2 DOF. In contrast the word "translational" has a mathematical meaning. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, let $\mathbf{a}$ be some fixed vector, the translation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ along $\mathbf{a}$ is the transformation which maps $x\mapsto x+\mathbf{a}$. In particular, since $\mathbf{a}$ can be chosen to be in any direction in a 3 dimensional space, there are 3 DOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "degrees of freedom" comes down to is really information. If a train is sitting on a rail initially at position $x=0$ and I tell you

> The train moves forward/backward $10 ~\text{meters}$

Then, after only being given *one number*, you have all the information you need to deduce the final position of the train, namely, $x=\pm 10~\text{meters}.$

On the other hand, if we have a particle in free space initially at position $\mathrm{r}=0$ and I tell you

> The particle moves forward/backward $10~\text{meters}$

You **don't** have enough information to determine the final position of the train. The particle could be in infinitely many places,  like $(0,0,10)$ or $(1,2,\sqrt 5)$, etc. One number is now **not enough**. In order to convey the final position of the particle, you need at least *three numbers*. This is what three degrees of freedom means.